# Obtaining tokens from async storage as null

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, asyncstorage

I want to get token for setting up automatic login in my react native app. I have written getTokens and setTokens functions as shown below:

```
export const getTokens = (cb) => {
    AsyncStorage.multiGet([
        '@NBA_App@token',
        '@NBA_App@refreshToken',
        '@NBA_App@expireToken',
        '@NBA_App@uid'
    ]).then(values => {
        cb(values);
    })
}

export const setTokens = (values, cb) => {
    const dateNow = new Date();
    const expiration = dateNow.getTime() + (3600* 1000)

    AsyncStorage.multiSet([
        ['@NBA_App@token', values.token],
        ['@NBA_App@refreshToken', values.refToken],
        ['@NBA_App@expireToken', expiration.toString()],
        ['@NBA_App@uid', values.uid]


    ]).then(response => {
        cb();
    })
}
```

Details:
I am not able to get the tokens on reloading app using componentDidMount. I get the token array as 'null'.

[image]

Comment: Using react-native to make an app for the same. https://github.com/lopeselio/React-Native-NBA-app